# LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE in PHP

Tags: php, load, local, load-data-infile

I am trying to load an .xml file from my ftp server into my mysql DB.
When I do this in the DB as an sql command it works perfectly fine.

But when I try to do it with PHP it does not work. I´ve tried many different ways.

SQL Command.

```
 LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'min_url' INTO TABLE table_name ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<product>'
```

My PHP looks like this.

```
$sql = " LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'min_url' INTO TABLE table_name ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<product>'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

So I am trying to do the exact same thing just with PHP. I even "created the php code for the command in my DB" and it still does not work. Everything untill the mysql_query is fine.

Versions
Serverversion: 5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1-log

```
Apache/2.2.12 (Ubuntu)
MySQL klientversion: 5.1.37
PHP-tillägg: mysqli
```